# What's the difference between "http-proxy" and "request"?

Tags: node.js, proxy, request, io.js

I need to create **forwarding** proxy (not reverse proxy), there are two packages for Node.js [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and [request](https://github.com/request/request)

I don't understand what's the difference between those in case of creating proxy? Are they doing exactly the same, or there are some tricky corner cases?

http-proxy

```
var http = require('http');
var proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer();

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: "http://" + req.headers.host
  });
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

request

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  req.pipe(request(req.url)).pipe(res);
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

Comment: They both are fowarding proxies only. So actual functionality wise they both are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples you've given are functionally the same, though I would still prefer `http-proxy`, as it already comes with some assumptions that you are specifically creating reverse/forward proxy requests.

Comment: Could you please explain more about those subtle differences?